# Voltage drops after connecting two batteries in parallel

Tags: voltage, batteries, circuit-analysis

I have two batteries 12V GEL 130Ah, each charged to 14.4V. After connecting them together in parallel, the voltage drops gradually and equalizes at 12.99V. (I use 10mm^2 short cables to connect them together so I wouldnt expect much of a drop at the cable.)

I would expect voltage to stay the same. Why does the voltage drop occur? Does it mean that the battery bank is somehow faulty?

Comment: And if you don't connect them in parallel does the voltage fall to 13 V as well?

Comment: No, no load is connected so it stays at 14.4V

Comment: 14.4V is the maximum charging voltage. It's really hard for me to believe that if the batteries set for awhile, disconnected from the charger, that the voltage is still 14.4V. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Batteries set off the charger for ~30sec, no load applied in the meantime

Comment: So the scenario is this: the batteries are fully charged and then connected together in parallel, and as soon as it happens the voltage starts dropping...

Comment: As @ElliotAlderson said; the voltage of your batteries cannot be 14.4V in rest, only during and shortly after charging. My bet would be that they would go to 13V after like, half an hour anyway? Since you connect them in parallel within 30 seconds, you speed up the process because they are never 100% exactly the same. So a small current flows to equalize them, which is enough to lower the voltage to 13V more quickly. I'd say your batteries are fine.

Comment: @AdamWolski: No problem. Just curious; did you measure the voltage after, say, half an hour? Did they drop, or stay at 14.4V? Or if you connect a really small load?